# AMD proprietary drivers

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, vga, hp-pavilion

I decided to install proprietary video driver to my HP Pavilion g6.
My system is Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn (updated yesterday).
Ok, i downloaded AMD Installer from official site.

```
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-14.301.1001-x86.x86_64.run --buildandinstallpkg
```

Now logs:

```
Created directory fglrx-install.Bn1Y9d
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-14.301.1001......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Generating and Installing package: Ubuntu/utopic
Package /home/efog/fglrx-14.301.1001/fglrx_14.301-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Package /home/efog/fglrx-14.301.1001/fglrx-dev_14.301-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Package /home/efog/fglrx-14.301.1001/fglrx-amdcccle_14.301-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx.
(Reading database ... 393855 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack fglrx_14.301-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx (2:14.301-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Preparing to unpack fglrx-amdcccle_14.301-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (2:14.301-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx (2:14.301-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-14.301 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-23-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-23-generic
Done.

fglrx:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...........

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.10.20140925-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:14.301-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-10ubuntu2) ...
fglrx_14.301-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb fglrx-amdcccle_14.301-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Cleaning up removed packages
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.Bn1Y9d
```

Every time i writing `aticonfig` i get `aticonfig: No supported adapters detected.`

But:

```
efog@efog-pc:~/fglrx-14.301.1001$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
```

Now i am scared to reboot :D Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has an Additional Drivers utility, which will show you what proprietary additional drivers are available to be installed and you can also install the proprietary graphics driver from the Additional Drivers utility, which is the better way to do it unless you're a gamer with a very new graphics card who needs the very latest version of the proprietary graphics card driver from the official AMD website.

Maybe you can boot and login to your desktop environment and fix this or maybe you'll get a black screen when you reboot, but you can also fix it from the black screen.

1. To bring up a text-only console use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then you will get a text-only virtual console which shows you a login prompt.
2. To uninstall the proprietary graphics driver from a text-only virtual console, login and run the command: `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh`
3. To start the Additional Drivers utility from the desktop environment search for *Additional Drivers* in the Dash and click the Additional Drivers icon.
4. There is also a text-only terminal program to show the available graphics driver packages. From the terminal or from the console run: `ubuntu-drivers devices`
5. [AMD Catalyst Drivers 14.9 needs kernel-headers on 14.10, although it is missing a version for Utopic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541469/amd-catalyst-drivers-14-9-needs-kernel-headers-on-14-10-altough-it-is-missing-a). This is yet another reason to choose a proprietary graphics driver from the Ubuntu repositories instead of downloading it from the official AMD website.

Hopefully some of these tips will help you to get this issue sorted out. In Ubuntu everything you need to do to install, uninstall or get information about a graphics driver can be done from a terminal or from a text-only console, so if you make a mistake you can fix it, even if you can't login to your graphical desktop environment.

Comment: I already got black screen and fixed it from console. But i still want to install proprietary drivers, because i cant play some games w/o them. Ty for advices, i will try it.

Comment: Run the `ubuntu-drivers devices` command before you install anything. You need to see the results of running that command.

Comment: `efog@efog-pc:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00001002d00006840sv0000103Csd00001840bc03sc00i00
model    : Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (Radeon HD 7670M)
vendor   : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
driver   : fglrx-updates - distro non-free
driver   : fglrx - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-ati - distro free builtin recommended`

Comment: Upd: installed using aptitude.. But now: `$ aticonfig \r\n
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected`.

Comment: Ty for still helping me :D But i have no more drivers. `efog@efog-pc:~$ sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sh: 0: Can't open /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh`, `efog@efog-pc:/usr/share/ati$ ls
fglrx-install.log  LICENSE.TXT`

Comment: [Removing Catalyst/fglrx](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx) says if fglrx-uninstall.sh doesn't exist use: `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*` and reboot to uninstall the graphics driver from the Nvidia website manually. I can't comment any more unless you delete most of your old comments. I also can't open a chat room at Stack Overflow to continue the discussion, because it's off topic at Stack Overflow, so delete some comments.

Comment: When i run my ubuntu in recovery mode and installed generated packages, `aticonfig` worked OK, but after reboot i got black screen (fixed). When i am installing packages from GUI or simly not recovery mode, it says `no supported adapters` T_T

Comment: `--purge` saved my soul :D Thank you very much! I want to add you 100000 reputation :) Now all working!